# django - copy header from admin to all templates

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

So what I want to do is add the django admin header within my own base template for my project. I copied over the base.html from admin templates to my project. Can I somehow put {% block header %} tags within base.html and then call it within my own base template for my project?

```
{% block header %}
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="branding">
    {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
    <div id="user-tools">

        {% trans 'Hi,' %}

        <strong>{% filter force_escape %}{% firstof user.first_name user.username %}{% endfilter %}</strong>.
        {% block userlinks %}
            {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
            {% if docsroot %}
                <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% trans 'Documentation' %}</a> /
            {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /
            <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- END Header -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending my main template from the admin 'base.html' template and going from there. A little messy but it works

Answer (score 0):

All templates that extend from `'base.html'` would contain the content inside `{% block header %}` and `{% endblock %}`, as long as they do not override the block or its ancestors(by removing the `{% block header %}...{% endblock %}` part).

If there are templates that do not extend from `base.html`, you could put the code into their common base, or use something like [inline tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) or [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Also, for the code to work properly for authenticated users, you need to ensure there is `user` variable in context: normally it's already there, or you need to re-enable `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"` if you've removed it before, check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)